# Best scripting language for Windows GUI EXE

Tags: php, perl, sockets, wmi

I'm writing a simple WMI-based monitor application that sends monitoring data over a TCP Network socket to an Android app. I have no issue writing the Android App with Titanium Mobile  (JavaScript) so that it creates a socket and accepts the data. However I'm looking for the best (easiest and fastest) way to get the WMI data and send it over the TCP socket but with a *VERY* basic Windows GUI. The only reason for the GUI at all is so the user knows the software is running, and possibly they will enter IP here to connect to the android over wifi. Here's my situation so far:

- PHP and JavaScript are my strongest languages (being a web dev). I can write WMI/COM scripts with PHP and compile with Bamcompile to a Windows command line EXE. It only supports PHP4 and I'm not sure which GUI toolkit (if any) will work with it as it is so old, but I still prefer it for my basic Windows stuff.
- I've been playing around with Perl (Strawberry Perl) and realising its potential. But seeing as my main programming PC is on a proxy I'm having trouble getting [Tk](https://metacpan.org/module/Tk) installed, so again I'm without the GUI stuff. I've tried "ppm install Tk" and "cpan Tk" and have put in all my proxy details, it's even downloading lots of data/modules but I'm getting errors that I have no idea how to solve as I'm not yet a Perl person.
- I have tried WinBinder for PHP and double clicking the Windows .phpw files seems to work, but I'd have to package the whole thing up somehow and also the command prompt window in the background looks messy.
- I could use AutoIT 3 - it does GUI, sockets, all that sort of stuff, and compiles to EXE, but I would really prefer PHP or Perl for the learning experience and I'm just more used to their syntax.
- Python looks great but a bit different to PHP or Perl so I'm not going to spend the time to learn it just at the moment. Will probably switch to it down the line though as it seems to have a very interesting structure.

I suppose the main issue I'm facing is that I could write this app for PHP and just Bamcompile it but I need to get the users input and let them know that something is running. I also presume using something like Wapache to just show a web browser with no toolbar wouldn't work because the PHP has to run in a continuous loop and that would crash any "browser"?   Will this work?

```
set_time_limit( 0 ); // 0 means never timeout

ignore_user_abort(true); // continue running when browser closes
```

So any ideas? Jscript and JSC ?

Bear in mind that I don't want to learn any Microsoft .Net stuff or complex C languages, or Java.

I'm sure I can do something like this with my current skills in PHP / JavaScript? No?

Comment: No, PHP wouldn't be the best answer IMHO.

Comment: I know it's not the best answer. But is it a possible answer ? :-D

Comment: I don't think so. And even if it was (doing some hacks), PHP is not designed for that. PHP is not like C++ or other command-line languages. PHP is supposed to run once and send HTML to the browser. Lately AJAX was added (featuring Javascript), but still Javascript do a request, the PHP script is run once and then output is sent to the browser. PHP is not a possible choice in my honest opinion.

Comment: You really don't want to write a socket application in PHP 4. Try node JS perhaps, it's still a bad option, but sure beats PHP in socket programming. Though I am unsure how you'd compile it as an executable.

Comment: You cannot compile PHP code into an executable.  If you want a GUI on Windows you need to use C/C++, Java, or a .NET language.

Comment: Take a look at PHP Desktop that embeds a Chrome browser and a web server, and acts kind of as a PHP to EXE compiler. See: https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/

Comment: Cheers for the update Czarek, I will indeed take a look at that. however since this question I've learned a lot of Python and if I still worked in IT, I think I would definitely use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had problems installing [the `Tk` module](https://metacpan.org/module/Tk) for my Strawberry Perl, but found that it installs manually just fine. Take a look at

```
perldoc permodinstall
```

to understand the process.

Perhaps the simplest way - if your CPAN is downloading packages correctly - is to run the cpan shell and say

```
cpan> look Tk
```

which will download and unpack the module for you and then shell out to a command prompt with the unpack directory as your current location. Here you can go ahead and say

```
perl MAKEFILE.pl
dmake
dmake test
dmake install
```

as described in *perlmodinstall*. (`dmake` is the flavour of make used by Strawberry Perl.)

My personal preference for a GUI library is the [wxWindows API `Wx`](https://metacpan.org/module/Wx) which is designed from the ground up to be portable and has a *look and feel* that depends on the platform where it is running. But you are likely to get more help using `Tk`, so the choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Most languages you've given there are going to use cross platform GUI libraries, and that is unnecessary hassle when you've said you want a Windows GUI. You will just end up making more work for yourself.

Everyone is going to want to sell you their language here. They wouldn't use it if they didn't think it was the best. So I guess I might as well jump in (disclaimer: written by an AutoIt MVP):

AutoIt will allow you to make small windows applications very quickly out of the box, it's one of the things it really does excel at. It's also entirely native, which in most cases means it's a lot easier to work with provided you don't intend to move over to linux any time soon.